# It is not one rather than the other.

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

It is not one rather than the other. 
Q: Could you tell me what this mean? I can't translate/understand it at all.

Comment: Really some context (leading up to the example) needs to be given.

Answer (score 1):

> It is not one rather than the other.

This statement means that an "either-or" choice is not involved.  It is not either the one or the other.  *Both* could be involved.

You could paraphrase it like this:

> It is not a situation of "the one or the other".